# Split a square into two small squares of different sizes.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Is it possible to divide a square with a side length of $5n$ into two contiguous squares with a side length of $3n$ and $4n$ inside without reassembly the pieces?

In the case if the two resulting squares can be assembled from small squares. If multiple cuts are allowed to be put back together and call the result a square, then yes.Take $n=1$ as an example, we can cut out a $4×4, 2(3×1),$ a $2×1$ and a $1×1$ square and build up a $3×3$ from the $4$ smaller pieces. But, in the case of contiguous  squares, I think it is impossible geometrically.  Is there any mathematical proof to confirm this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your problem is not clear enough, maybe some picture would help to undestand what are you asking.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I want to say can a square be divided into two smaller squares, each of a different size?

Comment: So... is reassembly allowed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no it is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The original square has 4 corners. Each corner will have to be covered by one of the small squares. (And that small square will have the same rotation as the original square)

By pigeonhole principle, one of the small squares will cover at least two corners of the original square.

This is impossible, because the distance of those two corners is at least the side length of the initial square, which is strictly greater than the side length of any small square.